# Should I check my TypeScript definition files for external libraries into git?

Tags: git, typescript

I am using [TSD](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) to manage the TypeScript definition files for a web application I am developing.

Should I check the TypeScript definition files for the external libraries I am using (managed via Bower) into git in addition to the `tsd.json` file?

Similar discussions exist for Bower and NPM dependencies, where the [NPM documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git) says no, and afaik Bower no longer gives a recommendation (used to say [yes](https://web.archive.org/web/20140625034714/http://bower.io/#installing-packages-and-dependencies)).

The definition files are quite lightweight, so I am leaning towards checking them in. Any opinions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a developer should run `npm install` after checking out your repo, why not have `tsd install` run automatically? It's easy to add it to `scripts` in `package.json`:

```
// package.json
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "tsd install"
}
```

The argument for not checking in generated files and dependencies is not merely to reduce the weight of the repository. It's also about trusting a script to keep things up-to-date, rather than human decision. And it reduces noise in commits when minor changes occur in the generated files.

A contrary argument could be made: if you're concerned that the `tsd` resources will go missing, checking them into your repo will guard against that. But the paranoid should check in the npm modules as well.

Comment: Just a note... since npm scripts run w/ `node_modules/.bin` in the path, there is no need for other developers to have tsd installed globally. (unless they are adding new definitions to the repo/project)

Comment: @Brocco That was the "missing link"! One reason I didn't mention in my question was that I didn't want do require developers to install `tsd` globally. Thanks!

Comment: how can you know that the developer has tsd installed globally? do you include that in the devDependencies of npm's package.json ?

Comment: @danfromisrael As per Brocco's comment above, tsd doesn't have to be installed globally to run as an npm script.

Comment: I don't think that `.d.ts` files should be checked into git in all situations, but won't `postinstall` also run when users `npm install` the published package? Seems like an unnecessary step for users who just want to consume the transpiled javascript in their own projects.

Comment: The OP said "The definition files are quite lightweight."

Comment: Now that `tsd` is deprecated, it's recommended to migrate to `typings`. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598876/why-is-tsd-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

Since I include "typings/tsd.d.ts" in tsconfig.json its now part of the build process, 
And I don't wont to maintain .gitignore with subdirectories of "typings/" , simple its better ...

and its more like a vote that an answer :)

As an example : I recently added in a project definition from the npm package instead of the definitely typed repo , but I added it to typings/tsd.d.ts because is the only definition file I reference in tsconfig.json ... ergo I can't relay any more in tsd to keep the defintions in sync, then.. check it in ... 
I could just simply add another definition file choosing arbitrary where to place it and reference this other definition file compilation too, but is more work more complicated and the result is the same, but only one file to keep the reference chain working.