# Why is TSD deprecated?

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, tsd

[Official tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269) annouced that tsd is deprecated and recommend using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) instead. Why is TSD deprecated? What is the difference between tsd and typings. What is the advantage of typings?

Comment: "*This improvement has effectively make TSD maintenance redundant..."* – Sounds like reason enough...?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the first link you provided:

> TSD link is flawed and not really a solid long-term solution - as it relies on ambient modules, causes duplicate identifiers and generally forces users to re-install sub-dependencies

From the second link: [why](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/faq.md#why)

And so on: [Typings, the Registy and Versions](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/typings-the-registry-and-versions.md)